# change Property Of **Custom Component Popup** From **Main.mxml**

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I want to change Property Of **Custom Component Popup** From **Main.mxml** (Main Application)
My Custom Component is ->

```
public class PropertyPanel extends Panel
.....
```

***in it I have***

```
public function minimisePanel(e:MouseEvent):void{

            effResize.heightTo = previousHeight;
            effResize.widthTo = 200;
            this.x = parentApplication.width - 320;
            effResize.play([this]);
        }
```

***In Main Application I Called It As -->***

```
private function AddPropertiesPanel():void{
    var PropWindow:IFlexDisplayObject;
    PropWindow =    PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, Property_Panel, false);
    /*Property_Panel is Property_Panel.mxml*/
}
```

***And In Main Application I Want to -->***

```
public function setCurrObj(event:TransformEvent):void{
/*Some Magical Stuff Required Here*/
}
```

Comment: If I understand; make the PropWindow an instance variable in your Main.mxml class; then you can easily access it in the setCurrObj method.

Comment: I am Dummy About it Can u please add it as answer PlzPlzPlz

Comment: public var PropWindow:IFlexDisplayObject;
private function AddPropertiesPanel():void{
 
 PropWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, popop, false);
 PropWindow.y = anshu_trans.y-100;
 PropWindow.x = this.width-320;
}
i tried this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the popup as a variable local to the function; store it as an instance variable on the Main.mxml class:

```
public var PropWindow:IFlexDisplayObject;
```

The AddPropertiesPanel() method will change like this:

```
private function AddPropertiesPanel():void{
    PropWindow =    PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, Property_Panel, false);
    /*Property_Panel is Property_Panel.mxml*/
}
```

And then you can easily access properties on the panel instance in other methods:

```
public function setCurrObj(event:TransformEvent):void{
 PropWindow.someProperty = someValue
}
```